Stripe API Not Returning Results
I'm trying to retrieve a subscription using the Stripe PHP SDK.   Everything appears to be in order, except I'm getting no response.   AFAIK the secret key is okay and the subscription ID is valid.  It returns a 200 response code and no errors.

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php';

$getVars = $_GET;

if (isset($getVars['id'])) {
    $subid = $getVars['id'];
} else {
    http_response_code(400);
    exit;
}

$apikey = "sk_test...";

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($apikey);

$stripe->subscriptions->retrieve($subid, []);


I think the issue here is you're not saving the results of $stripe->subscriptions->retrieve($subid, []); to a variable. If you save this to a variable and then log that variable, do you see the details of this subscription?

no if I save it as a variable it comes back undefined

(1) 200 OK means "Everything worked as expected." (2) You said you have saved the data to a variable, Did you do something like this:  $var = $stripe->xxxx->retrieve(xxxxx); ?

Yes I tried that, $var comes back undefined

AFAIK there's no reason this would ever be undefined. Maybe edit the question to show exactly the state of your code and how you assign the variable/access it/print any debug lines. Also consider doing things like logging all possible errors(https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/9769731)
